# Scala: get outer class from inner class in constructor

Tags: scala, scala-reflect, scala-implicits

I have an anonymous inner class, and I want to acces the (anonymous) outer class of it in the constructor. So I want to implement this method:

```
new Outer {
  new Inner {

  }
}

class Outer {

}

class Inner {
  def outerClass: Outer = ???
}
```

Comment: It is impossible without stack trace magic. Maybe we can suggest you better solution to your problem?

Comment: I have tried this with implicit parameters, I failed, but maybe it is possible for you?

Comment: I believe that you trying to solve some other problem by doing this. If it is true, explain it to us. Maybe it is better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do this using implicits easily enough (I assume both `Outer` and `Inner` can be modified, but the code using them should look like in the question). Declarations:

```
class Outer {
  implicit def o: Outer = this
}

class Inner(implicit val outerClass: Outer) {
}
```

Usage:

```
new Outer {
  new Inner {
    // can use outerClass here
  }
}
```

or

```
new Outer {
  val inner = new Inner {

  }

  // inner.outerClass
}
```

And I can imagine this being useful for DSLs, but be sure you(r API's users) actually want it first!

Answer (score 2):

What speaks against this approach?

```
new Outer { self =>
  new Inner(self) {

  }
}

class Outer {
}

class Inner[A](outerClass:A) {
  println("CLASS: " + outerClass.getClass)
}
```